# Roku ECP input command and verification

Tags: roku

I want to write bash scripts in order to automate roku application on roku 4 using Roku ECP with curl.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Press the home button
curl -d '' http://192.168.1.140:8060/keypress/home
#Wait for 3 seconds
sleep 3
#Start GMO application
curl -d '' http://192.168.1.140:8060/launch/appId1
#Wait for 3 seconds
sleep 3
#Check active app
curl http://192.168.1.140:8060/query/active-app
```

How is it possible to verify or interact within the application? Such as, if 'Go' button is available on the screen, click on it. Or just verifying any elements on the screen.

Thanks!